# update_attributes not inserting all attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I'm trying to use update_attributes and accepts_nested_attributes_for to update some children objects (days_events) from the parents (location) controller.

Everything looks good in params hash but when I attempt to use assign_attributes or update_attributes the actual dates don't get updated.The first days_event record is created in the database successfully as it should with the event_id and location_id but the start_date and end_date fields are empty.

There aren't any model restrictions on the date fields either.

Here's the code in my location(parent) controller:

```
def update
    logger.debug('PARAMS HASH********'+params.to_s)

    @total_forms=params[:total_forms].to_i
    @current_form=params[:current_form].to_i

    @location = Location.find(params[:id])       

    @location.update_attributes(params[:location])
  end
```

Here's my params hash:

```
{
"utf8"=>"Γ£ô", 
"_method"=>"put", 
"authenticity_token"=>"Mz2GzRmqxrygy01d2LdkE6ZZY+fJK1PSlVhFKlVUme8=", 
"location"=>{
    days_events_attributes"
=>{
    "0"=>{
        "start_date"=>"03/14/2013", 
        "end_date"=>"03/14/2013", 
        "_destroy"=>"false", 
        "event_id"=>"588"
        }, "
    1"=>{"
        start_date"=>"", 
        "end_date"=>"", 
        "_destroy"=>"1",
        "event_id"=>"588"
        },
    "2"=>{
        "start_date"=>"",
        "end_date"=>"", 
        "_destroy"=>"1", 
        "event_id"=>"588"
        }
    }
 }, 
 "total_forms"=>"2", 
 "current_form"=>"0", 
 "commit"=>"Add Date s for Next Location", 
 "action"=>"update", 
 "controller"=>"locations", 
 "id"=>"871"
}
```

Comment: Which DB are you using? Check the date format, MySQL for example uses the YYYY-MM-DD format, if you input an invalid format it will just reject it.

Comment: Can you post the model code for the relations and nested attributes?

Comment: look at your attr_accessible

Comment: Would be good to see the console log when you try to run the update

Comment: @sergelerator nailed it. its a mysql database and it didn't like the date format, it was rejecting 3/14/2013 dates but if i tried to enter 4/4/2013 swapping the day and month didn't matter and it went in fine. Switch it to an answer and ill mark it solved. thanks guys!

Comment: @sergelerator what is the best way for me to address modifying the date format before it goes in? Do I need to iterate though all of them in the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the date format, MySQL for example uses the YYYY-MM-DD format, if you input an invalid format it will just reject it.

If you want to normalize the date format regardless of what you get as input, I would suggest adding a `before_validation` hook to your model and do it there. Check the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349254/rails-way-formatting-value-before-setting-it-in-the-model) for a suggestion, it doesn't deal with dates (it shows how to format a price attribute) but it should give you an idea of what you need to do.

Should you need help formatting the date drop a comment here and I'll get to it as soon as I can.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks! I tried adding a before_validation to the days_event model and I'm getting a nilClass error. Any suggestions?

Comment: I only get the nilClass error when the date is a format that won't work ex. 3/15/2013 instead of 4/4/2013..

Comment: Are you getting this error while accessing the date attribute? I just ran some tests and it looks like, setting an invalid date format on a `Date` attribute results in the model rejecting the value. This will have to be handled in the Controller... (oh noes ):) I'm thinking a `before_filter` in your `ApplicationController` could format your dates. But if you have control on the client-side code, try setting the proper format there, I don't very much like the idea of adding that kind of noise to your `ApplicationController`

Comment: That is when I'm getting the error. I have access the client side code but I want the user to see the date in the MM/DD/YYYY format. Could you point me in the right direction for the before_filter option?